# Does JavaScript affect the Page Source?

Tags: javascript

I have never actually noticed this which is why I am now curious. My site uses much AJAX and depending on the response, it puts it into div's using the `.innerHTML`. Example:

```
$("#cont-btn")
  .click(function() {
      var colourID = document.getElementById("colour")
        .value;
      var styleID = document.getElementById("style")
        .value;
      var sizeID = document.getElementById("size")
        .value;
      if (done == 0) {
        if (cat == 0) {
          var catag = document.getElementById("catagorey")
            .value;
          $.get("catHan.ashx", {
              cata: catag
            })
            .done(function(tD) {
              cat = 1;
              document.getElementById("style")
                .innerHTML = tD;
              $("#style")
                .slideToggle("slow");
            });
        } else {
```

I inspect the element using `Google Chrome` and the Page source updates however, when I actually `View the page Source` it doesn't appear?

My dev-environment is C#/ASP, is this meant to happen? I've never actually noticed it before. Why does it not update if the `inspect element` notices the change?

(I ask because incrementing your page on Google can be effected since there bots only reads `page source`)

Image when viewed source: [image] 
The above image shows the elements after they have been added to, nothing shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see in View Source is literally the *source code* which was sent from the server to the browser. What you see in the DOM inspector ("Elements", or whatever it's called in your browser), is a representation of the DOM, the modified in-memory data structure which represents your website.

The DOM can be manipulated, writing back to the source would be pretty pointless.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's crazy how I went through programming without even noticing or learning that! Ill mark when I can (got to wait)

Answer (score 1):

No, Javascript does not affect the source page.

The source page is the page sent by your server.

The code that you see updated by JS is the DOM (Document Object Model)

Comment: Thanks for this also! :D